# Snowflake - Lateral Flatten creating duplicate rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm creating a new table (my_new_table) from another table (my_existing_table) that has 4 columns, product and monthly_budget have nested values that I'm trying to extract:

Product column is a dictionary like this:

```
{"name": "Display", "full_name": "Ad Bundle"}
```

MONTHLY_BUDGETS is a list with several dictionaries, the column looks like this:

```
[{"id": 123, "quantity_booked": "23", "budget_booked": "0.0", "budget_booked_loc": "0.0"} , 
{"id": 234, "quantity_booked": "34", "budget_booked": "0.0", "budget_booked_loc": "0.0"}, 
{"id": 455, "quantity_booked": "44", "budget_booked": "0.0", "budget_booked_loc": "0.0"}]
```

The below is what I'm doing to create the new table and unnest from the other table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE my_new_table as (
 with og_table as (             
    select
      id,
      parse_json(product) as PRODUCT,
      IO_NAME,        
      parse_json(MONTHLY_BUDGETS) as MONTHLY_BUDGETS
    from my_existing_table
) 
    select
      id,
      PRODUCT:name::string as product_name,
      PRODUCT:full_name::string as product_full_name,
      IO_NAME,           
      MONTHLY_BUDGETS:id::integer as monthly_budgets_id,
      MONTHLY_BUDGETS:quantity_booked::float as monthly_budgets_quantity_booked,
      MONTHLY_BUDGETS:budget_booked_loc::float as monthly_budgets_budget_booked_loc
      from og_table,
      lateral flatten( input => PRODUCT) as PRODUCT,
      lateral flatten( input => MONTHLY_BUDGETS) as MONTHLY_BUDGETS);
```

however once my new table is created and I run this:
select distinct id, count(*)
from my_new_table
where id = '123'
group by 1;

I see 18 under the count(*) column when I should only have 1, so it looks like there are a lot of duplicates, but why? and how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LATERAL FLATTEN produces a CROSS JOIN between the input row and the flatten results.

So if we have this data

```
Id, Array
1, [10,20,30]
2, [40,50,60]
```

and you do a flatten on Array, via something like:

```
SELECT d.id,
  d.array,
  f.value as val
FROM data d
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => d.array) f
```

```
Id, Array, val
1, [10,20,30], 10
1, [10,20,30], 20
1, [10,20,30], 30
2, [40,50,60], 40
2, [40,50,60], 50
2, [40,50,60], 60
```

for for you case, given you are doing two flatten's for each ID you will have many duplicate rows of ID.

Just like above if on my output if I did a `SELECT ID, count(*) FROM output GROUP BY 1` I will have the values `1,3` and `2,3`

Comment: Thank you Simeon this example was great, I just had to read over it a few times  to grasp. thanks so much for responding!